# Redirect local url/IP to other local url/IP

Tags: http-redirect

I have an Windows application that communicates with IP camera. This application have a button and when I press this button HTTP GET command is send

GET http://192.168.1.100/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?usr=username&pwd=password&cmd=getDevState HTTP/1.1

and as result I get snapshot/image from the camera

Because this camere is not function good I bought new camera. But this new camera have new url to snapshot image

http://192.168.1.100/GetSnapshot[1]

As result the application is not warking any more. Because I cant edit the code of exe application, there is any way so I can redirect in Windows (netsh or route) this

http://192.168.1.100/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?usr=username&pwd=password&cmd=getDevState

to this

http://192.168.1.100/GetSnapshot[1]

Thank you in advanced